# PHP: Where to place return 'false' value?

Tags: php

Is one of the following functions better than the other, in terms of where to place the 'return false' statement?

Function #1:

```
function equalToTwo($a, $b)
{
    $c = $a + $b;
    if($c == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Function #2:

```
function equalToTwo($a, $b)
{
    $c = $a + $b;
    if($c == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I personally prefer #1 for its simplicity... but this is almost as controversial as tabs vs. spaces or vi vs. emacs.

Comment: @scunliffe: Thanks. I agree. I didn't know this was such controversial topic!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the two; you should choose whichever one is most obvious and readable.

I would usually use an `else`.

Note that your particular example should be written as

```
return $c == 2;
```

Comment: Good point. Do not be afraid of using comparison operators outside control structures. Booleans are values too!

Comment: I am accepting your answer because you answered the question AND provided an alternative, which, in my opinion, is a lot nicer!

Answer (score 2):

What about just:

```
return ($c == 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case choose whichever is more easily readable for you, since it's such a small function.

In cases where the function is much larger it's usually best to do something like this...

```
function do( $var=null ) {

    if ( $var === null ) {
        return false;
    }

    // many lines of code

}
```

In this case it would matter. Fail right away. Because it is much more readable than...

```
function do( $var=null ) {

    if ( $var !== null ) {
        //many lines of code
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between them. In my opinion they're both equally readable, and there is no noticeable performance different either.